# Zookeeper & Kafka error KeeperErrorCode=NodeExists

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have written a kafka consumer and producer that worked fine until today.
This morning, when I started zookeeper and kafka, my consumer was not able to read messages, and I found this in the zookeeper logs:

```
INFO Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x151c41e62e10000 
     type:create cxid:0x2a zxid:0x1e txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a 
     Error Path:/brokers/ids 
     Error:KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists for /brokers/ids   
     (org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor)
```

Comment: Looks like you are trying to start another kafka broker with same broker id

Comment: Thank you. It's very strange. I follow the same procedure of other times. What thing could' I try to fix the problem?

Comment: Try restarting zookeeper followed by kafka once

Comment: Got the same issue, restarting nodes is ok, Kafka doesn't log anything, only zookeeper is complaining, yet the consumers can't subscribe.

Comment: Faced the same issue. Had to clear all logs and zookeeper files to fix this.

Comment: plzz provide more details about your problem

Comment: @Rahar: Your solution worked for me... :) But this issue eaten up my whole day... :( I **deleted all files** from `'/tmp/zookeeper'` and `'/tmp/kafka-logs'` .... and my consumers are again able to process messages..

Comment: Could you provide your Kafka server version, Zookeeper version, Kafka-client version? Can you also give the topic information and metadata of the given topic/partitions.

Answer (score 22):

Look for **log.dirs** in your server.properties file and delete all the Kafka and zookeeper logs from there and try restarting zookeeper and Kafka respectively. I was facing the same issue and doing this resolved it.

Comment: Why this answer is not selected as an accepted answer? It should be

Comment: Would I lose all data if I delete the folders?

Answer (score 1):

I want to add extra information:
I was trying to set up Kafka with Zookeeper on Windows and also with Docker Compose - faced the same issue.

I realize that the Kafka node needs to wait for Zookeeper for about 20-30 seconds before it could start successfully.
So my batch script on Windows would be:
REM first cd to the Kafka root folder

```
@echo off
start cmd /k ".\bin\windows\zookeeper-server-start.bat .\config\zookeeper.properties"
timeout /t 20 /nobreak >nul
start cmd /k ".\bin\windows\kafka-server-start.bat .\config\server.properties
```

I am not really sure what zookeeper does in this 'break' time but it helps. Try it and leave a comment if it helps.

Comment: Thanks, to run zookeeper, kafka-server and consumer one by one, i was also making same script. it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

go to Kafka root directory and look for the logs file. and clear all logs. For instance:
say your kafka is installed in the downloads folder:

```
cd ~/Downloads/kafka_2.13-2.6.0
rm -rf logs
```

It will resolve the issue.